# how to rescue from AbstractController::ActionNotFound exception in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my application controller I am rescuing from a bunch of different exceptions to display my own error page with no problem.  For example:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found
rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate, with: :server_error
# etc...
```

However the following does not work:

```
rescue_from AbstractController::ActionNotFound, with: :not_found
```

Which I understand is because the exception is raised in AbstractController before we get to my application controller to be able to rescue it.

I would like to be able to rescue from this exception too and I haven't been able to find a solution that works.
I've tried sending exception to the router by doing:

config/application.rb

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

and in config/routes.rb

```
get "*any", via: :all, to: "application#not_found"
```

which does not work and seems to be the most common answer for Rails 3 and 4.  I'm using Rails 5.0.0 and any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I got here while searching for a way to serve "static files" that still used my layouts, but show a 404 page if anything was requested that I didn't have, so in case anyone else was looking for the same, here's what I did:

I ended up making a new controller that only has one action in it to handle either case:

```rb
# app/controllers/static_controller.rb
class StaticController < ApplicationController
    def static_or_404
        render params[:static]
    rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
        render :not_found
    end
end
```

and then at the very bottom in my routing:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
get '*static', to: 'static#static_or_404'
```

In your case you could skip the static part, and then you wouldn't have to rescue and you could just call your `not_found` inside the action. For a different use case, you could redirect to your root or something.

Answer (score -1):

I had to solve this same problem today. This might not be the best way for all scenarios but it worked well for me. Here's what I did:

In Rails 5 we've got this ApplicationController that from which the other controllers inherit. This means you can use classic ruby inheritance methods to catch actions that might not exist in all controllers and handle them with a nice 404.

Here's an example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    show_nice_404
  end

  def show
    show_nice_404
  end

  # new, edit, etc..
  # you can also use alias if you like

  private

  def show_nice_404
    render 'some/404.html', layout: false, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Again, since this is the ApplicationController and all other controller inherit from it, the legit actions will simply override the ones you've defined here and when not overridden it will yield a 404 page.

NOTE: I only did this for the common RESTful actions, but you could try it with method_missing although I would make sure your test suite is solid before trying it.